# multiple imageview inside uiscrollview creating issues when rotate the device

Tags: ios, iphone

In  `viewdidload`of ViewController I wrote this code

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
 object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
arrImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"IMG_0621.PNG",@"IMG_0643.PNG",@"IMG_0658.PNG",@"IMG_0701.PNG", nil];
if (!scrollView) {
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 568)];
}else
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 568);
[scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
[scrollView setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:NO];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
for (int i=0; i<arrImage.count; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * scrollView.frame.size.width;
    imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSString *strImage = [arrImage objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:strImage];
    [imageview setImage:image];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageview];
}
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [arrImage count], scrollView.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

and in my notification, I have written this

```
UIDevice * device = note.object;
switch(device.orientation){
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:{
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,568);
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

        for (int i =0; i<arrImage.count; i++) {
            CGFloat xOrigin = i * scrollView.frame.size.width;
            imageview.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 320,568);

        }
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 * [arrImage count], 568)];
    }break;

    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:{
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568,320);
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        for (int i =0; i<arrImage.count; i++) {
            CGFloat xOrigin = i * 568;
            imageview.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 568,320);
            imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(568 * [arrImage count], 320)];
    }
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:{
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568,320);
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

        for (int i =0; i<arrImage.count; i++) {
            CGFloat xOrigin = i * 568;
            imageview.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 568,320);
        }
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(568 * [arrImage count], 320)];
    }break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationUnknown:

        break;
    default:
        break;
};
```

When orientation changes my scrollview change its frame but my imageview inside scrollview is not changing frame according to orientation . I also tried imageview transform but did work for me.

Comment: As per my understanding you should have used collectionView rather scrollView along with UIImageView then you wouldn't have to take care of rotation issue.

Comment: its my need it just a small part of my work can not use collection view

Comment: In that case check with your constraints of uiimageview with respect to scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

With my understanding you should have used the UICollectionView instead of UIScrollView but as you mentioned that you can not use collectionView then in that case you need to check with the constraints that you have applied to the UIImageView.

Below are screenshot of my demo.

**Portrait:**

[image: Portrait]

**Landscape:**
[image: Landscape]

Below are screenshot of constraints that I have applied but do change as per your need and satisfaction.

**ScrollView constraints**
[image: ss1]

**One of the UIView constraint with respect to UIScrollView**
[image: ss2]

NOTE : in your case you need to apply constraints programmatically.